# Fetching flag does not update when using a single fetching reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am in the process of cleaning up my fetching flags. By following the [best practice](https://medium.com/stashaway-engineering/react-redux-tips-better-way-to-handle-loading-flags-in-your-reducers-afda42a804c6), I am using a separate reducer to store all isFetching flags. In doing so I do not have to maintain multiple isFetchingFlags in my reducers.

Although I followed the explanation exactly, my isFetching flag does not jump from `IsFetching: true` (data currently being fetched) to `IsFetching: false` (data successfully fetched) in this new configuration. My fetching flag remains at `IsFetching: false` all the time. I have checked my code several times, but I cannot find my error.

**Story Action:**

```
// GET STORY
export const getStory = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch ({type: GET_STORY_REQUEST});
  dispatch(showLoading());
  axios.get( apiBase + "/story/retrieve/", tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_STORY_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
      dispatch(hideLoading());
    })
  .catch(err =>{
      dispatch({
        payload: returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status),
        type: GET_STORY_FAILURE });
      dispatch(hideLoading());
    })
};
```

**Loading Reducer**

```
import {GET_STORY_SUCCESS,GET_STORY_REQUEST, GET_STORY_FAILURE} from "../actions/types.js";

const loadingReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  const { type } = action;
  const matches = /(.*)_(REQUEST|SUCCESS|FAILURE)/.exec(type);
  
  // not a *_REQUEST / *_SUCCESS /  *_FAILURE actions, so we ignore them
  if (!matches) return state;  
  
  const [, requestName, requestState] = matches;
  return {
    ...state,
    // Store whether a request is happening at the moment or not
    // e.g. will be true when receiving GET_STORY_REQUEST
    //      and false when receiving GET_STORY_SUCCESS / GET_STORY_FAILURE
    [requestName]: requestState === 'REQUEST',
  };
```

**Loading Selector**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
export const createLoadingSelector = (actions) => (state) => {
  // returns true only when all actions is not loading
  return _(actions)
    .some((action) => _.get(state, `api.loading.${action}`));
};
```

**Story Component**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getStory} from '../../actions/story';
import { createLoadingSelector } from '../common/loading';




export class Story extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
      story: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
      getStory: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
   };

     componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getStory();
  }
  



  render() {
    const { story } = this.props.story;
   
    return (

  <Fragment>

        <h2>Stories</h2>

      </Fragment>

    );
  }
}


const loadingSelector = createLoadingSelector(['GET_STORY']);

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    const story = state.story
    const isFetching = loadingSelector(state)
    console.log (isFetching)
    console.log (story)
  return { story, isFetching}
};


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getStory}
)(Story);
```

I'm happy for every clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a middleware?
Remember that redux does not support asynchronous actions by default.
If not try to configure the redux-thunk middleware.

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk